# Converting image to jpg Angular 4

Tags: image, angular, typescript, npm

I am using Angular 4 with TypeScript for a web application. I am allowing users to upload a thumbnail profile photo from their device as either a png, jpeg, or jpg, and I want to convert that photo to a jpg on the frontend. I am looking for some way to do this, as the file type is readonly.

The reason that I am doing this is so that when users load the profile page, they don't have to download large images so the page is quick. I think that converting to a jpg might be the best bet because when tested with a sample image, a png of an image was 35.4KB while a converted jpg of the same image was 6.7KB. If there is a better solution, I would love to hear it!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: 35 KB is still very small. But I've never seen anyone nor any camera use PNG for pictures anyway. You can just safely accept JPEG images only, and nobody will be annoyed.

Comment: @JBNizet I still want my users to be able to upload images that they might find from online as other file extensions. If it really is a rarity, I can reconsider but I thought that PNG is a pretty common format.

Comment: It's a common format for icons like avatar icons. But not for pictures. And encoding PNG icons in JPG won't help, because PNG is a better format for such images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just wrote some code like your requirements, here is what I did:

1. load a local image by [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) and add a listener to its `onload` event
2. in the `onload` listener, create an "Image" object by `new Image()`, and set "src" attribute by the loaded image "src" (Data URL format)
3. create a "Canvas" element, and draw the image on this canvas
4. use [Canvas.toDataURL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL) to fetch the converted image data (in base64)
5. post the image data to server

After you draw an image to canvas, call `Canvas.toDataURL()` will get the canvas content in [Data URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-CN/docs/Web/HTTP/data_URIs) string, please note that it's the canvas data not original image data, for example, if image size is 100 x 100 and canvas size is 50 x 50, you'll get an image in 50 x 50 pixel with this function, so if you want a full size image, you need to resize the canvas to the certain size.

this function has two parameters:

> canvas.toDataURL(type, encoderOptions);

- type - A DOMString indicating the image format. The default format type is image/png. in your code, **set to "image/jpeg" in your case**
- encoderOptions - A Number between 0 and 1 indicating image quality if the requested type is image/jpeg or image/webp.

Here is my "preview and upload" function write in TypesScript for reference:

```
preview(input: HTMLInputElement) {
        if (input.files.length) {
            let reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = (e) => {
                if (!this.img) {
                    this.img = new Image();
                }

                this.img.src = (e.target as any).result;
                this.img.onload = () => {
                    // omit code of setting 'dx', 'dy', 'width', 'height'
                    let ctx = <CanvasRenderingContext2D>this.canvas.nativeElement.getContext('2d');
                    ctx.drawImage(this.img, dx, dy, width, height);

                    let dataUrl = (<HTMLCanvasElement>this.canvas.nativeElement).toDataURL('image/jpeg', 0.7);
                    this.uploadService.upload(dataUrl).then((resp: any) => {
                        if (resp.key) {
                            this.asset.image = resp.key;
                        }
                    });
                };
            }

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }
```

I omitted some variables: `dx, dx, width, height` in the above code, I use these variables to adjust image position (for clipping purpose).

This is JavaScript example:

```js
function _elm(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id);
}

_elm('fileInput').onchange= function(event) {
  if (event.target.files.length) {
    var fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onload = function(event) {
      var img = new Image();
      img.src = event.target.result;
      _elm('sizeRaw').innerText = '+ data-url size ' + event.target.result.length;
      img.onload = function() {
        var canvas = _elm('canvas');
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 200, 200);
        var dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 0.5);
        _elm('output').innerText = dataUrl;
        _elm('sizeNew').innerText = '+ data-url size ' + dataUrl.length;
      }
    };
    fileReader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
  }
};
```

```css
#canvas {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

#output {
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<h3>Input file <span id="sizeRaw"></span>: </h3>
<input id="fileInput" type="file" accept="image/*">
<h3>Canvas</h3>
<div>
<canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
</div>
<h3>Output <span id="sizeNew"></span>: </h3>
<div id="output">
</div>
```